# Javascript fetch. How to handle result

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

Im currently playing around with fetch and was wondering how i can make the callbacks a bit cleaner but still use arrow function. For example i want to make a loop on the success. What syntax should i use?

Code

```
fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.items))
  .catch(e => console.log('error'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much else to do than use a couple of curly brackets and iterate in the usual way

```
fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
             for (const item of data.items) {
                // stuff
             }
          })
          .catch(e => console.log('error'))
```

You could of course put that in a function and call the function instead, if that makes you happier.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i looked for.